# Как удалить все слова после определенного знака?

Tags: c#

Имеется текст

> Test of file. To be or not to be? Test of file.
>   Another text. The gray wolf jumped over the grey wall! Another text.
>   Hey. What are you doing? Hey.
>   Please. Check. Enter the count! Please. Check.

Моя программа удаляет все что ДО точки и после выводит сначала все предложения со знаком **?** и потом со знаком **!**. С одной стороны правильно. Но как мне удалить все что после предложений со знаком **?** и знаком **!**

Вот код моей программы:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
        string[] textsplit = text.Split('.');
        foreach (string str in textsplit)
        {
            if (str.Contains('?') == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str.Trim());
            }
        }
        foreach (string str in textsplit)
        {
            if (str.Contains('!') == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str.Trim());
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string trimmed = str.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(trimmed.Substring(0, trimmed.IndexOf('?') + 1));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Получилось

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
    IEnumerable<string> phrases = Regex.Matches(text, @"(.+?)(\.|\?|!)").Cast<Match>()
        .Where(x => x.Value.LastOrDefault() != '.')
        .Select(x => x.Value.Trim())
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastOrDefault()).ToArray();

    foreach (var phrase in phrases)
        Console.WriteLine(phrase);
```